# Dynamic LINQ method for IndexOf

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to make use of dynamic LINQ and I'm stuck. This is what I'm aiming at:

In my testData I have names like: Lille, Nille and Bob. I want Lille and Nille in the result.

```
var p = CreateParameterExpression<Individual>();
var indexOf = IndexOfExpression<Individual>(p, "Name", "ill");
var exp = EQ(p, indexOf, 1);

var result= testData.Where(exp);
```

The missing piece of code looks like this:

```
static Expression<Func<T, bool>> EQ<T>(ParameterExpression parameterExp, Expression<Func<T, int>> func1, int value) 
{
    if (true)
    {
        return f => true;
    }
    else
    {
        return f => false;
    }
}
```

I can't figure out what to put here: "if (true)"

Please help

Comment: I can't figure out where `CreateParameterExpression` and `IndexOfExpression` are coming from.

Comment: Please give us a [mcve] to work from.

Comment: What LINQ are you using: LINQ to Objects / SQL / EF 6.x / EF Core 2.0 / 2.1 / 3.x / 5.x / 6.x? What database provider?

Comment: @NetMage, there is no need to know which LINQ provider is used. It is standard Expression Tree.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv E.g. if you are using LINQ to Objects, why bother with `Expression` at all? Just use `Func<>`...

Comment: @NetMage, for performance reason for sure. You can compile dynamic delegate.

Answer (score 1):

I watched a video on YouTube that kicked me in the right direction. Her's my code:

```
static Expression<Func<T, bool>> EQ<T>(ParameterExpression parameterExp, Expression<Func<T, int>> func1, int value)
{
    var exprBody = Expression.Equal(func1.Body, Expression.Constant(value));
    var finalExpr = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(exprBody, parameterExp);
    return finalExpr;
}
```